# MASShortcut no such module

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoapods

I've been try use [MASShortcut](https://github.com/shpakovski/MASShortcut/releases) and following the instructions there I've added it using cocoapods. I then added it to my *<proj>-Bridging-Header.h* file and `import`ed it in my main swift file but I keep getting the error

> No such module 'MASShortcut'

Here's my setup:

*AppDelegate.swift:*

```
import Cocoa
import Carbon
import MASShortcut

var kShortCut: MASShortcut!

@IBOutlet weak var shortcutView: MASShortcutView!

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        ... omitted ...    
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        shortcutView.shortcutValueChange = { (sender) in

            let callback: (() -> Void)!

            if    self.shortcutView.shortcutValue.keyCodeStringForKeyEquivalent == "k" {

            self.kShortCut = self.shortcutView.shortcutValue

            callback = {
                print("K shortcut handler")
            }
        } else {
            callback = {
                print("Default handler")
            }
        }
MASShortcutMonitor.sharedMonitor().registerShortcut(self.shortcutView.shortcutValue, withAction: callback)
```

and my *Podfile*:

```
target 'myapp' do

  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use   dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'MASShortcut', '~> 2'

  # Pods for myapp

  target 'myappTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

and finally *proj-Bridging-Header.h*:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <MASShortcut/Shortcut.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the AppDelegate should sort of look like. Note the absense of any `import MASShorcut`.

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var kShortCut: MASShortcut!
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    @IBOutlet weak var shortcutView: MASShortcutView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        shortcutView.shortcutValueChange = { (sender) in

            let callback: (() -> Void)!
            if self.shortcutView.shortcutValue.keyCodeStringForKeyEquivalent == "k" {

                self.kShortCut = self.shortcutView.shortcutValue

                callback = {
                    print("K shortcut handler")
                }
            } else {
                callback = {
                    print("Default handler")
                }
            }
            MASShortcutMonitor.shared().register(self.shortcutView.shortcutValue, withAction: callback)
        }
    }
}
```

The bridging header should look like this:

```
#ifndef Testin_Bridging_Header_h
#define Testin_Bridging_Header_h

#import <MASShortcut/Shortcut.h>

#endif /* Testin_Bridging_Header_h */
```

`Shortcut.h` imports all the other header files. Testin was the name of my app (to test of course)

Some other tips:

- Make sure you set the bridging header in your application's build settings.
- Try building from the MASShortcut scheme if it doesn't build the framework initially.
- The AppDelegate doesn't have lifecycle events, you need to use either NSViewController or NSWindowController subclasses to use lifecycle methods (ie viewDidLoad).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm passed the `no such module` error but am now getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`  on the `shortcutView.shortcutValueChange = { (sender) in` line.

Comment: @Sparkmasterflex Probably means you didn't connect your outlet, therefore it is nil.